# Add Expire Headers Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.2

there is a way to add Expire Headers for external static components?

Magento 2.2.2 CE

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**you can not control headers from external domain - but you dont have to.**

many optimization are just misused.

the most important numbers are:

1 - TTFB - Time To First Byte -
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse/audits/ttfb

2 - FCP - First Contentful Paint - https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse/audits/first-contentful-paint

take care of these two, and you will be good to go.

also compress all your images, especially jpegs, even down to 65 quality + progressive.

and enable assets cache in varnish config:

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3/app/code/Magento/PageCache/etc/varnish5.vcl#L102

forget about everything else.

Answer (score 2):

> **Expires Headers are used by the web browser in order to specify the period for a page component to staying in the cache. We can control
> expires for static contents which should have longer expires headers.
> You can activate this by adding the following lines below.**

**In .htaccess file :-**

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
############################################
## Add default Expires header
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>
```

[6 Tips To Speed Up Magento Frontend Performance](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/speed-up-magento-frontend-performance/)

[Reference Link](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/magento-2-development/9781785289897/ch08s09.html)

Comment: you can not control headers for external domain. please read the question, do not confuse with your spam.